# Why does the image display normally in github, while not in gitbook?

Tags: git, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, gitbook

I have a document which is hosted in `github` and synchronizes to `gitbook`. The image of this doc display normally in [github](https://github.com/NanXiao/FreeBSD-101-Hacks/blob/master/posts/shutdown.md):

[image]
While it can't be displayed in [gitbook](https://nanxiao.gitbooks.io/freebsd-101-hacks/content/posts/shutdown.html):

[image]
The code of embedding image is as follows:

```
![image](https://github.com/NanXiao/FreeBSD-101-Hacks/blob/master/images/shutdown-h-now.JPG)
```

Why does the image display normally in `github`, while not in `gitbook`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in **gitbook** you need specify direct link(raw):

```
![image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NanXiao/FreeBSD-101-Hacks/master/images/shutdown-h-now.JPG)
```

**gitbook** is separate project and it can't understand **github** blob link.